# Having issue displaying a Digital-7 font

Tags: fonts, adobe-fireworks

I am trying to use the [Digital-7](http://www.1001fonts.com/digital-7-font.html) font for GUI in Adobe Firework, but the "1" charactere is displayed "incorectly" (sorry, I don't even know how to discribe it) like in the image below.

I don't know if this is a limitation of the font itself

Note: the green font from a capture of the [Digital Clock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dv.dc&hl=en), so am not 100% sure if they it use the same font.

[image: Digital Clock]

Comment: Are you using the [mono version](http://www.1001fonts.com/digital-7-font.html#character-map-mono)? The "1" should be in the correct place with that.

Comment: Let me check again

Comment: @Cai That was is, It work! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [mono version](http://www.1001fonts.com/digital-7-font.html#character-map-mono), which has fixed glyph widths and will fit as you expect. The regular version of the font has proportional glyph widths so you aren't getting the space around the "1".

You can see the difference in glyph widths here:

**Mono**

[image]

**Regular**

[image]